# After Updating VS 2022 for Mac not getting anything in output window. It's just showing purple color

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

Today I installed all updates available for Visual Studio 2022 for Mac. After updating, my application works fine but as soon as an app runs "Application Output" window also opens in the bottom panel. Generally, it has a white background and shows the app logs and activity with black text.

But after updating VS 2022 for mac "Application Output" window opens but with purple color and without logs (text).

[image]

Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions or fixes to get output window content.

Comment: Have you tried deleted and reinstalled VS for mac?

Comment: Very weird but without doing anything it starts working properly. Maybe just restart VS or system works.

Comment: It might be random scenarios. On the next day when VS restarted everything was normal.